# Flutter WebviewPlugin remove header and footer of website

Tags: webview, dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

By implementation of FlutterWebviewPlugin, I want to show a particular website in a widget but without header and footer.
is this possible in Flutter?
I guess there is a function in FlutterWebviewPlugin class .evalJavascript('some code') but don't know how to use this function. can I add javascript code to this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

String url = "https://flutter.io/";

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Webview Example',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      routes: {
        "/": (_) => Home(),
        "/webview": (_) => WebviewScaffold(
          url: url,
          withJavascript: true,
          withLocalStorage: true,
          withZoom: true,
        )
      },
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomeState createState() => HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final webView = FlutterWebviewPlugin();
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController(text: url);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    webView.close();
    controller.addListener(() {
      url = controller.text;
    });
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    webView.dispose();
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("WebView"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: controller,
                ),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Open Webview"),
                onPressed: () {

                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/webview");
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess you are looking for https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/webview_flutter (early stage)

Comment: The example in plugin repo has a usage of evalJavascript https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin#-example-tab-

Answer (score 9):

I suggest using Flutter's official WebView plugin: [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)

The plugin also has a method that can run Javascript using [`WebViewController.evaluateJavascript(String)`](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebViewController/evaluateJavascript.html). This method is recommended to be run after `WebView.onPageFinished` callback.

Your WebView widget should look like this.

```dart
WebView(
    initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
    onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
      _webViewController = webViewController;
      _controller.complete(webViewController);
    },
    onProgress: (int progress) {
      print("WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)");
    },
    onPageStarted: (String url) {
      print('Page started loading: $url');
    },
    onPageFinished: (String url) {
      print('Page finished loading: $url');

      // Removes header and footer from page
      _webViewController
          .evaluateJavascript("javascript:(function() { " +
              "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];" +
              "head.parentNode.removeChild(head);" +
              "var footer = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];" +
              "footer.parentNode.removeChild(footer);" +
              "})()")
          .then((value) => debugPrint('Page finished loading Javascript'))
          .catchError((onError) => debugPrint('$onError'));
      },
);
```

Here's a complete sample that you can try.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  WebViewController _webViewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            _webViewController = webViewController;
            _controller.complete(webViewController);
          },
          onProgress: (int progress) {
            print("WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)");
          },
          javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>{
            _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
          },
          navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
              print('blocking navigation to $request}');
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            print('allowing navigation to $request');
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {
            print('Page started loading: $url');
          },
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            print('Page finished loading: $url');

            _webViewController
                .evaluateJavascript("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];" +
                    "head.parentNode.removeChild(head);" +
                    "var footer = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];" +
                    "footer.parentNode.removeChild(footer);" +
                    "})()")
                .then((value) => debugPrint('Page finished loading Javascript'))
                .catchError((onError) => debugPrint('$onError'));
          },
          gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
        );
      }),
    );
  }

  JavascriptChannel _toasterJavascriptChannel(BuildContext context) {
    return JavascriptChannel(
        name: 'Toaster',
        onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
          // ignore: deprecated_member_use
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text(message.message)),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

How the app looks running

[image: demo]

Comment: `.evaluateJavascript()` has been removed. The recommended way is to use `.runJavaScript` and `.runJavaScriptReturningResult`

Answer (score 5):

```
_webViewController.runJavascript(
          "document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.display='none'");
      _webViewController.runJavascript(
          "document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0].style.display='none'");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`flutter_inappwebview`](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) plugin (I'm the author) and inject an `UserScript` at `UserScriptInjectionTime.AT_DOCUMENT_START` to hide or remove HTML elements when the web page loads (check [JavaScript - User Scripts official docs](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/webview/javascript/user-scripts) for User Scripts details).

As I have already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74627723/4637638) for a similar issue, here is a code example using the current latest version 6 ([6.0.0-beta.18](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview/versions/6.0.0-beta.18)) with URL https://getmobie.de/impressum that removes the header and footer HTML elements:

```dart
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (!kIsWeb &&
      kDebugMode &&
      defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
    await InAppWebViewController.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(kDebugMode);
  }
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();

  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("InAppWebView test"),
        ),
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: InAppWebView(
              key: webViewKey,
              initialUrlRequest:
                  URLRequest(url: WebUri("https://getmobie.de/impressum")),
              initialUserScripts: UnmodifiableListView([
                UserScript(source: """
                window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
                  var header = document.querySelector('.elementor-location-header'); // use here the correct CSS selector for your use case
                  if (header != null) {
                    header.remove(); // remove the HTML element. Instead, to simply hide the HTML element, use header.style.display = 'none';
                  }
                  var footer = document.querySelector('.elementor-location-footer'); // use here the correct CSS selector for your use case
                  if (footer != null) {
                    footer.remove(); // remove the HTML element. Instead, to simply hide the HTML element, use footer.style.display = 'none';
                  }
                });
                """, injectionTime: UserScriptInjectionTime.AT_DOCUMENT_START)
              ]),
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                webViewController = controller;
              },
            ),
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

For your use case, use the right CSS selector inside the user script js source to correctly get and remove the header and footer HTML elements from your web page!

[image: Android example]
[image: iOS example]

Comment: this is not working for me. can you help me

Answer (score 0):

[Lorenzo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4637638/lorenzo-pichilli) answer didn't work for me well. The element always returned null. So here's can be a possible solution:

```
onLoadStop{
  _webViewController.evaluateJavascript(
  source:"
     var main = document.querySelector('#__next'); 
     var header = main.querySelector('.sc-FTTUS.jnFTCj'); 
     var footer = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];
     header.remove(); 
     footer.remove()"
);
}
```

using such nested locator,it worked well.