# How to remove the header and footer from website using web view package in flutter

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, webview

I am using [webview package](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) and want to remove the header and footer of the website https://getmobie.de/impressum/ (I have the rights to display the page) in flutter.

Below is my code :

```
    class ImprintScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImprintScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ImprintScreen> createState() => _ImprintScreenState();
}

class _ImprintScreenState extends State<ImprintScreen> {
  late WebViewController controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: WebView(
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        initialUrl: 'https://getmobie.de/impressum',
        onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
          setState(() {
            this.controller = controller;
          });
        },
        onPageStarted: (url) {
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print('Website: $url');
          }
        },
        onPageFinished: (url) async {
          await controller.runJavascriptReturningResult(
              "document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.display = 'none'"
          );
          await controller.runJavascript("javascript:(function() {" +
        "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];" +
        "head.parentNode.removeChild(head);" +
        "var footer = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];" +
        "footer.parentNode.removeChild(footer);" +
        "})").then((value) => debugPrint('Page finished Loading Javascript')).onError((error, stackTrace) => debugPrint("$error"));
        },
      )
    );
  }
}
```

But i am not able to remove the header and footer of the web page when displays on mobile app.

Can you please suggest what is the mistake in above code.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the Javascript inside the "onPageStarted" for hide header & footer .

Checkout the below code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';


void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ImprintScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class ImprintScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImprintScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ImprintScreen> createState() => _ImprintScreenState();
}

class _ImprintScreenState extends State<ImprintScreen> {
  late WebViewController controller;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: WebView(
            initialUrl: "https://getmobie.de/impressum/",
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (webViewController) {
              controller = webViewController;
            },
            onPageStarted: (url) {
                print('Website: $url');
                //Hide header & footer
              if (url.contains('https://getmobie.de/')) {
               //Added delayed future method for wait for the website to load fully before calling javascript
                Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 900), () {
                  controller.runJavascriptReturningResult(
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('elementor elementor-7715 elementor-location-header')[0].style.display='none';"
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('elementor elementor-2727 elementor-location-footer')[0].style.display='none';"
                  );
                });
              }
            },
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

[Screenshot of hidden header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pOlT.png)

[Screenshot of hidden Footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/584sI.png)

Comment: This question question was already asked and answered. Follow this link shorturl.at/evY26 and see if the solution provided matches the response provided or better the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`flutter_inappwebview`](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) plugin (I'm the author) and inject an `UserScript` at `UserScriptInjectionTime.AT_DOCUMENT_START` to hide or remove HTML elements when the web page loads (check [JavaScript - User Scripts official docs](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/webview/javascript/user-scripts) for User Scripts details).

Here is a code example using the current latest version 6 ([6.0.0-beta.18](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview/versions/6.0.0-beta.18)) with your URL https://getmobie.de/impressum that removes the header and footer HTML elements:

```dart
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (!kIsWeb &&
      kDebugMode &&
      defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
    await InAppWebViewController.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(kDebugMode);
  }
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();

  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("InAppWebView test"),
        ),
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: InAppWebView(
              key: webViewKey,
              initialUrlRequest:
                  URLRequest(url: WebUri("https://getmobie.de/impressum")),
              initialUserScripts: UnmodifiableListView([
                UserScript(source: """
                window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
                  var header = document.querySelector('.elementor-location-header'); // use here the correct CSS selector for your use case
                  if (header != null) {
                    header.remove(); // remove the HTML element. Instead, to simply hide the HTML element, use header.style.display = 'none';
                  }
                  var footer = document.querySelector('.elementor-location-footer'); // use here the correct CSS selector for your use case
                  if (footer != null) {
                    footer.remove(); // remove the HTML element. Instead, to simply hide the HTML element, use footer.style.display = 'none';
                  }
                });
                """, injectionTime: UserScriptInjectionTime.AT_DOCUMENT_START)
              ]),
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                webViewController = controller;
              },
            ),
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

[image: Android example]
[image: iOS example]